# What drive does a user profile gets stored in windows machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, hard-drive

On my Laptop I have two drives : C, D and Network drives. At any time i can log in to any desktop on the network and my data is on any of this computers. I would presume the user profile is stored on the network drive and not in the C drive . But i would like to know where i can find my profile file like the bash profile in unix on my windows machine

I know this may sound generic, But an elaborate explanation will enhance my understanding?

Comment: Do you belong to a domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually three different directories which host your data. Local User, Roaming User and Application Data.

Normally you can find them via environment variables like %appdata%. Just enter that into your windows explorer's navigation bar and you should end up there. The other two directories are *usually* next to it.

If you are inside a domain the domain controller should move the settings inside the roaming user profile between machines during login.